# add a custom attributes to Payment method in order invoice detail page

Tags: magento2, sales-invoice

Want to display custom attribute in payment method section of sales order invoice view
[image]

Comment: you means after place order showing attribute in invoice view in back end???

Comment: @MohitPatel  yes, i have already save customer atribute in sales_order_payment table.
need to display here